# encontrar una fecha acorde a la llave primaria MYSQL fastApi

Tags: python, mysql, api

tengo una tabla en mysql workbench con 3 campos: msisdn,operator_id y last_port.

Necesito encontrar una fecha que contenga el campo last_port acorde a su llave primaria, que en este caso seria msisdn. Logro capturar la llave primaria desde la base de datos pero no se como capturar la fecha contenida en last_port.

models:

```
class PortabilidadInfo(Base):
      __tablename__ = "portabilidad"
      msisdn = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
      operator_id = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
      last_port = Column(Date, default=datetime.now(), nullable=True)
```

Adjunto codigo:

```
portabilidad_msisdn = '5688297219'  
## BUSCO MSISDN EN BDD ##
portabilidad_info = session.query(PortabilidadInfo).get(portabilidad_msisdn)

fecha_csv = '2022-04-03 06:00:00'
print("FECHA CSV: ", fecha_csv, type(fecha_csv))

# BUSCO FECHA EN BDD    ** ENCONTRAR FECHA ACORDE A LA PORTABILIDAD_MSISDN **
date_info = session.query(PortabilidadInfo).get(fecha_csv)
print("FECHA BDD OBJ: ", date_info, type(date_info))
```

Luego de este print me arroja un error de NoneType... Alguien sabe como puedo solucionar esto y encontrar la fecha?. Ayuda por favor.